# Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'. #new update

Tags: flutter, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run the app in the new flutter updated stable version 2.10.2 My code working fine before the update I'm getting this error now
android/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
```

}

```
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rollback Gradle version to `3.5.4`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`

Comment: I added this but not working.